# What is it called when we use "through which" "about whom", "whose", etc

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-pronouns

I would like to know how to refer to the sentance structure that is used in formal contexts, when  "through which", "for whom" etc. are typically used. Are these non-defining relative pronouns?

Sometimes they can can be combined:

> implicates a world amid and with which it proceeds

And often they make sentences more confusing:

> The understandings of action through which doings and sayings are
>   linked in practices encompass the understandings of action against the
>   background of which doings and sayings constitute specific actions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article about [relative clauses](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/relative-clauses) that addresses this particular construction:

> *4. Giving additional information*
>
> We use relative pronouns to introduce relative clauses, which tell us
>   more about people and things....
>
> We use who, whom, whose, and which (but not that) in relative clauses
>   to tell us more about a person or thing....
>
> **as object of a preposition:**
>
> He decided to telephone Mrs. Jackson, who he had read about in the
>   newspaper. That’s the programme which we listened to last night.
>
> - We sometimes use whom instead of who:
>
> He decided to telephone Mrs. Jackson, whom he had read about in the
>   newspaper.
>
> - The preposition sometimes comes in front of the relative pronoun whom or which:
>
> He decided to telephone Mrs. Jackson, about whom he had read in the
>   newspaper. That’s the programme to which we listened last night.